# PHP library for uploading images and editing/displaying them?

Tags: php, image, file-upload

I'm working on a course project, one of the features is to allow users to upload images and then later comment on them:

1 - What is the best php library for doing this?

2 - Is there any php library that would allow a user to highlight a region within an image and comment on it? (Kind of like what cageapp does?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a PHP library. Just write your own upload code. Or look it up, just don't copy and paste it without fully understanding it though. Expect to do some work yourself, libraries don't fix everything.

With regards to selecting a region in an image, you'll need to use javascript. Here's a jQuery plugin that can do this.

http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/